# PHP Redirecting to an app link

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink, header

I'm trying to redirect to an URL like this:

```
example://
```

to open a specific app. But when I use the `header()` function in PHP it redirects to

```
http://example//
```

when using `header('Location: //example://');`. It removes the `:` and I don't think it will work with http in front. Also when not using the // before the URL it ofcourse adds it to the end of the host URL of the current page.

Comment: What is `example://` supposed to be? The part of a URL before `:` is supposed to be a URL scheme like `http:`, `https:`, `mailto:`, etc.

Comment: Yes, in my case it's a custom URL to open an app, like explained here http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/07/30/how-to-launch-your-macios-app-with-a-custom-url/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with PHP only but you can with Javascript. You should have something like that :

```
$fullUrl = 'example://';
print('<script type="text/javascript"> window.location="'.$fullUrl.'"; </script>');
```

Anyway if your browser blocking Non HTTP(S) protocols you can't do it.

Comment: Was hoping to avoid using JS, but I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Thanks....was running into this same issue.  Was hoping for a clean and simple php redirect, but now I must write a basic html page with JS redirect.  Ugh.